# Can I retrieve a Facebook access token if I don't store it in my database?

Tags: facebook

I have been asked to look into whether or not I can retrieve a Facebook access token from Facebook if the user had granted permission in an earlier session.  The problem is that our business logic tier is maintained by a different group and is on a different release schedule from the web development group.  If I were to gain an offline access token, I might not be able to store it for up to two months.  For any users acquired in the meantime, is there a way that I can retrieve the token from facebook without further intervention from the user?

I would think that this might be a security hole, but one of our senior developers thinks that it is likely that facebook offers such a feature.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Don't bother storing the access token on a long term basis. If you have offline permissions (which you need for this to work), then you can ask for a new token as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

In short No.

But with the offline access request being complete.
You can request a new token without any user clicking.

You just get a new offline access token and use that. The same way as if you didn't request offline access, and the access token had expired, it doesn't explicitly say but it does work:

> In addition to the access token (the access_token parameter), the response contains the number of seconds until the token expires (the expires parameter). Once the token expires, you will need to re-run the steps above to generate a new code and access_token, although if the user has already authorized your app, they will not be prompted to do so again. If your app needs an access token with an infinite expiry time (perhaps to take actions on the user's behalf after they are not using your app), you can request the offline_access permission.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

That way you don't have to store them at all.
Unless you actually want to perform actions when the user is not using your Application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the access_token every time the user logs back in, offline_access or not !

You can get it in JS with FB.getAccessToken();

There is no way to retrieve (offline) access token, when the user is not actually logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the access token for a long period of time, you will be required to ask for the offline_access permission, otherwise the access token will only last a short period of time.  Either way, it is best to store it in a cookie or locally as it will certainly improve your app's latency.  But make sure to check its validity as often as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the access_token means, you have the permission to do things on behalf of the user. If you must do something without user FB login, you need the offline access_token. But be careful, the offline access_token will be ignored, when the user change his/her FB password, or delete the application.

So I hope there isn't any way to get another access_token without the user permission. I think the easiest way to check the access_token to make a /me?access_token= GET request, and check the answer. If the answer is an error, the access_token not working, you have to renew it.

To get access_token from somebody in the middle of the flow is a little pain. But you can also put variables to the redirect link.

Example:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=API_KEY&scope=email$redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_APP_URL%3F$param

$param could be a flow info like: flow=12342323

So when your user come back the $_GET['flow'] will be 12342323.